# Capacitor reduction with multiple voltage regulators

Tags: capacitor, pcb

I am designing a PCB with two voltage regulators, both have one electrolytic capacitors to stabilize the input voltage. I have two big capacitors in parallel in my board. I want to reduce them to one equivalent capacitor, but I don't know if that is a good idea.

The voltage regulator is XL7046.

[image]

I want use one cap of 100uF instead of two caps of 47uF.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that with the large electrolytic capacitor- combine them into one capacitor of double the capacitance and equivalent voltage rating on the same PCB. The dual ceramic capacitors should be retained and kept close to the individual XL7046 chips.

Keep in mind that sometimes we would prefer to split a single capacitor of (say) 100uF into two capacitors. Reasons include physical dimensions (maybe the height is an issue, but PCB area is not so important) and ripple current rating.